# sending complex viewmodel to controller from nested partial views - MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

looking for a bit of Ajax help here...

I have quite a complex view which is built on quite a complex ViewModel.

On the page I have 3 columns where each column represents a full journey which then breaks down to show the individual flights.

Each flight is represented by a box containing details (start and end locations, departure time, arrival time, operator etc)
The box also contains a dropdown list of all other possible flights that could be taken from this location (e.g. you might want to hang around the airport for an additional 6 hours, so you could choose a later flight!)

Anyway, by changing one possible flight, I'm going to have to update the entire column, because taking a later flight will mean subsequent flights might not be possible anymore.

Which leads to my question - is it possible for me to pass a complex viewmodel back to the controller via jQuery?  Can it be done using partial views that are nested inside foreach loops? 
All I want to do is update the column via ajax, but I can't see how to pass the viewmodel back.  I'm trying to avoid doing a full page reload because it will be quite a cumbersome search so ajax updates would be ideal

Here is some cut-down code for the process:

**Code for View (index.cshtml) - the jQuery is found here within the main view**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id="column-@groupCount">
        @Html.Partial("_JourneyColumnPartial", item)
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".flightItem").change(function (event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
        var cSelected = $(this).val();
        alert(cSelected);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Search/GetChangeInfo",
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({ cID: cSelected }),
            success: function (display) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Code for first partial view (_JourneyColumnPartial.cshtml)**

```
<div class="routeContainer">
    @Html.Partial("_ColumnItemPartial", Model)
</div>
```

**Code for child partial view (_ColumnItemPartial.cshtml)**

```
@{
    int journeyNumber = 1;
}
@foreach (var journey in Model.SelectedJourneys)
{
    List<JourneyDetails> list = Model.Journeys.Where(j => j.JourneyDateAndTimeID != journey && j.DepartureID == hub.DepartureID && j.ArrivalID == hub.ArrivalID).OrderBy(j => j.JourneyDateAndTime).ToList();
    <div class="box">
        <div class="journeytimes">
            <b>Depart</b> @hub.DepartureDate<br />
            <b>Arrive</b> @hub.ArrivalDate<br />
        </div>
        <div class="boxcontrols">
            <select class="flightItem" id="flightItem_@{<text>@Model.ColumnNumber</text><text>_</text><text>@journeyNumber</text>}">
                @foreach (var flight in list)
                {
                    <option value="@flight.JourneyID">@flight.ProviderName - @flight.JourneyDateAndTime</option>                                                    
                }                                            
            </select>

        </div>
        <!-- end of box -->
    </div>
    journeyNumber++;    
    <!-- end of box wrap -->
}
```

I know I've not included details about the ViewModel, but it is quite complex and includes generic lists of other classes so it is quite large.  The trigger for the ajax/jQuery is the change event of the dropdown list.

If this makes absolutely no sense, feel free to say and I'll try and clarify what I'm looking for!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by sending your data as json in your jquery call.

You can achieve this by simply create a javascript object like your ViewModel, and convert that javascript object to string by `Json.Stringify` method and set the string value to the `data` in the ajax call.

Comment: Ok, that sounds interesting.  How might you go about that - would you have to create each field manually in the javascript object?  What about the sub-classes in the viewmodel - would they have to be manually created as well?

Comment: Yes you have to create each field manually, as far as the subclasses are concern you have to create the properties of both subclass and parent class in a single object. When it comes to serialization on fields matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your issue is with sending the data or returning it but this will help you with returning it via ajax: http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/render-partial-view-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks - not got to that yet, but it may come in handy :)